# when we Take Screenshot then it will save with current date and time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am creating two methods as given below:

```java
public static String currentDateTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String cal1 = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    return cal1;
}
```

```java
public static void screenShot(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
    File scrnsht = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String datetime = GenericFunctions.currentDateTime();
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrnsht, new File("D:\\Screenshot1.png"+datetime));
}
```

But, when i use take screenshot method in my WebDriver script then a folder has been created, i want take screenshot with current date and time, please point me to where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "datetime" with "cal1" in:

```java
FileUtils.copyFile(scrnsht, new File("D:\\Screenshot1.png"+datetime));
```

OR

Try this

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
String destFileName = screenShotPath.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+"failure_screenshots_"+formater.format(calendar.getTime())+".png";
```

Comment: Also, that turn String datetime into a useless code, so you might want to remove that.

Comment: Would this not cause the file to not be a png? I would suggest `"D:\\Screenshot1-" + datetime + ".png"` more appropriate.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me.. if you provide me your new code regarding"when we take screenshot then it will save with current date and time."

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void screenShot(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
File scrnsht = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String datetime = GenericFunctions.currentDateTime();
FileUtils.copyFile(scrnsht, new File("D:\\Screenshot1.png"+datetime));
```

}

Your file will be looked like Screenshot1.png only, the datetime is not added anywhere.
Instead of that you can `FileUtils.copyFile(scrnsht, new File("D:\\Screenshot1"+datetime+".png"));`

It is also advised that instead using 1 you can use loop, or if function in case 1 already existed add 2 instead or something like that